# I am trying to pass a variable from shell script to adb shell command

Tags: android, bash, shell, adb

I am trying to pass a variable from a shell script to an `adb shell` command but I am facing some issue.

Code snippet:

```
x=0
while true;
do
        var="Dump_stat"
        var+="$x"
        p=$(adb shell cat /d/abc > /data/$var.txt | tr -d '\r\')
        x=$(( $x+1 ))
done
```

My requirement is with each pass through the `while` loop to save the file with a new name, but I'm seeing the error below:

```
/data/Dump_stat0.txt: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone point out what is going wrong here, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the redirection happens on your computer when there's no '/data' directory.

Try to quote the entire command

```
p=$(adb shell "cat /d/abc > /data/$var.txt" | tr -d '\r\')
```

BTW, I don't know why you are assigning to `p` or piping to `tr`, but that's a different story.

Comment: also he probably did not mean to escape the 2nd apostrophe in that `tr` command